# Wrapping div doesn't accept image height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

This is my first question, so please, be patient to me, thanks.

I am making website in wordpress.
I have div which wraps content with image on left and some paragraph on right. And the background of transparent-box have height of the text (which is shorter), and ends in the middle of image (which is on left).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="transparent-box">
  <img class="alignleft" src="img/img.jpg" width="480" height="319" />
  <div class="tr-text">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And style.css:

```
img.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.transparent-box {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p {
line-height: 1.34;
margin-bottom: 14px;
font-size: 15px;
```

}

If I used  it didn't helped me. I think the problem is easy to find solution, but I tried many ways which didn't work. I tried transparent-box auto or 100% height but it didn't work too.

Thank you so much!

Comment: edit: first, Welcome! will take a look:)

Comment: have you tried using a clearfix ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Comment: Oh I tried clear too, but after the last div, huge little mistake :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `display:inline-block` for your `.transparent-box`?

Comment: Nope, That wouldn't fix it, text would go to the left under the image

Comment: This worked too, and the paragraph is verticaly centered with image, which makes nice look. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fwtt9hLu/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="transparent-box">
    <img class="alignleft" src="img/img.jpg" width="480" height="319" />
    <div class="tr-text">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS::

```
.clear{
    clear:both;        
}
```

You have `float` for `img`. So you need to clear `float` property in order to get full height

Comment: Damn :) You were 5 sec faster:p

Comment: This is what helped me. I tried it but at wrong line. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :): **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/giaumn/L9osz68t/)**

```
overflow: hidden
```

this cause the same effect as K.B.M's solution.